# HttpResponse body is being altered

Tags: java, linux, web-services, http, firewall

We are facing a peculiar issue at the moment and we have no clue what is causing this.

We have a web-service hosted on serverA.
When this web-service is invoked from serverB (using the command, curl `http://serverA:8008/service/getId`), we get the required response. (the web service returns an Id which is an integer).

When the same web-service is invoked from serverC, we get the required response but the digit **2** in the response is getting replaced by **_** .

For example, we get **5002** when the web-service is invoked from serverB.
When the same web service is invoked from serverC, we get **500_**

We checked the wireshark details from serverA and the data going out from serverA is the same for both the servers.

We have no clue at the moment why this is happening. I would like to add that serverC is in DMZ while serverB is not.

Any input/help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: I have heard of situations where network switches can cause corruption but leave the CRC intact, when you run curl from serverA, does the return value come back OK?

Comment: @Gearoid - yes, we do not see any issues when the command is issued from any server. It happens only when it is invoked from serverC.

Comment: Is there a firewall between serverA and serverC?

Comment: Clearly the next step is to probe with Wire Shark at the NIC of serverB.  If you see the underscore, the firewall or other box in the network is clearly the problem.  If not, then it's the server.

Comment: Have you ever checked the wireshark details from ServerB and ServerC, if the inbound data is the same, then it must be something wrong with ServerC, otherwise it will be a networking issue.

Comment: @Gene, Jermaine Xu : yes, I have verified the packets using wireshark at the destination server and the packets are received corrupted. So, it is clear that the network/firewall is causing this but we don't know what it is!

Comment: Curl also goes through the same firewall?

Comment: The raw CURL output may be helpful here.  Something doesn't add up around the "5002" becomes "500_" part.  I've seen encoding issues and proxies cause behavior like this, but never as cut-and-dry as "5002" becomes "500_".  More like my umlats in German become indecipherable characters at the client.

Comment: We have already seen that sort of corruptions with "smart" firewalls that try doing protocol analysis (to see how many people consult do p2p over HTTP for instance). Try going HTTP/S if you can; firewalls are better crossed using ssl as they will not/cannot alter the content (or it is too buggy to be called a firewall).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your efforts, the issue is now resolved. It was an incorrect firewall rule that was causing this. I asked our network engineer how the firewall setting can alter http response body and following is the reply I got:

> For certain protocols the firewall does deep-level packet inspection,
>   so rather than just check the port number it actually looks into the
>   payload. This allows it to block malware, malformed packets that might
>   be exploiting a vulnerability and the like. So it know what to inspect
>   you have to specify in the rule what the traffic is, so you say it’s
>   on port 8008 and it’s HTTP. The problem was that for some reason this
>   rule had been set to use port 8008, but the traffic type was set to
>   passive mode FTP rather than HTTP. Once I corrected it to HTTP, it
>   started working.

Answer (score 1):

by gather the facts that

```
 1. Server doesn't change the response by its own.
 2. Web Service is giving the same response for the same input.
```

only culprit is your firewall, can you stop it for testing purpose and see if the response is coming as expected. OR
Try to check the firewall settings and create a hole/exception for web Service.

Comment: @saravana_pc This is should have been marked as an answer as the answer here is exactly what you found out!!

Comment: @renegadeMind - Pls see my comment above at "Oct 18 at 15:43". It was long established that the firewall is the issue. But the question was, what in firewall is causing this.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting ServerB in DMZ too and see what happen.
If it acts the same its a network issue.
If not you might have 2 different versions of code on the servers.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds to me like you have special characters in your URL and they cause the overwriting of the port number, but only if the characters are recognized in the character set. Can you use a hex editor to check the URL for special characters (backspace, specifically)?

Answer (score 0):

I can't solve your problem, but look for any transcoders on the path. 
Send request from server C to server A.
1) wireshark at A, to see if it receives request correctly. A possible transcoder may convert host-less urls to host-ful ( GET /service/getId to GET http:// serverA:8080/service/getId), or may drop Host header etc. But if you see nothing wrong here proceed to step 2.

2) wireshark at B, to see if response is valid. Look if Content-Type is set correctly. If set correctly, and still getting manipulated try adding header Cache-Control: no-transform. Many transcoders respect that. If this also fails and can't remove any possible transcoders, viruses you may have go to step 3.

3) Just go https, it is immune to such things.

Answer (score -2):

This is a feature of Apache, designed to hide parts of the HTTPresponce.
I did not see a fix immediatly, and do not have the time to look right now. I'll try to edit one in later.

If you want to try to find it, here is the link to the documentation: http://xianshield.org/guides/apache2.0guide.html

use [Ctrl] + [F] to find this statement (without qoutes) "Configure and build the Apache Server"

Comment: sorry, the link above did not provide any information about the issue. Could you please provide more inputs on this?

Comment: This is the most ridiculous answer I have ever seen on SO.  The premiss is the web server is going to "hide" part of the HTTP Protocol?  Like that has a chance at working.  Its like saying "We are going to speak english, but only with no verbs or nouns".

Comment: Blame the Apache server, not me